# Pop element from a list into a list [Python 3.x]

Tags: python, list, blackjack

I'm making a BlackJack game in Python, but it doesn't respect my indexation. It pops a random element from all my sublists, not just from one list.

```
import random

class Deck(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck_of_cards = []
        self.base = []
        for i in range(0, 13):
        troca = {
            0: 'A',
            10: 'J',
            11: 'Q',
            12: 'K'
        }
        if not i in (0, 10, 11, 12):
            self.base.append(i + 1)
        else :
            self.base.append(troca.get(i))

        for i in range(0, 4):
            self.deck_of_cards.append(self.base)


        def random_card(self, quantidade):
            print(self.deck_of_cards)
            for i in range(0, quantidade):
                 self.deck_of_cards[random.randint(0, 3)].pop(random.randint(0, 13))


        print(self.deck_of_cards)

bar = Deck()
bar.random_card(2)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your code's indentation is broken and that makes it invalid Python. Please [edit] your question, paste your code exactly, then select it and click `{}` or press Ctrl+K to indent it. Stack Overflow will treat it as a code block. While you're editing, please see if you can clarify your question. [ask] has some good tips for asking questions effectively.

Comment: *Note:* If you pop an element from a list it will lose an element. This code `random.randint(0, 13)` can fail because it may try to access `13` when that index no longer exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the salient code:

```
for i in range(0, 4):
    self.deck_of_cards.append(self.base)
```

You don't have four separate sublists: you have four references to the *same* sublist  If you want four copies of the original, you have to make those copies.  Try this:

```
for i in range(0, 4):
    self.deck_of_cards.append(self.base[:])
```

Comment: Well, it worked, thank you so much, but, why does it work? :p

Comment: Again, your original code simply copied the reference to the list.  The update forces the interpreter to make a whole-list slice of the list, which generates a new object.  If you want more examples and details, search on line for list references vs copies.

Comment: [:] means make a new sub list, taking from the first element to the last. its like [0 : len(base)]

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(0, 4):
    self.deck_of_cards.append(self.base
```

Your list `deck_of_cards` contains 4 references to your list `base`

You need to insert new lists into your deck_of_cards, not the same one 4 times!

Also, this code is broken, but I'll let you figure out why on your own

```
self.deck_of_cards[random.randint(0, 3)].pop(random.randint(0, 13))
```

Comment: I need to make the ranges dinamically, I think

Comment: Bingo! And you need to try again in case deck_of_cards[x] is empty